# Switch statement to match several cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement

I want to write a switch statement that will go through first 2 cases if they are both true. If not, only match the one that is true.

```
var vehicle = {main: false, detail: false};

switch(true) {
   case (states.data.currentState.indexOf('main.vehicle') !== -1):
      vehicle.main = true;
      break;
   case (states.data.currentState === 'main.vehicle.detail):
      vehicle.detail = true;
      break;
 }
```

My problem is that after first break the switch statement ends and doesn't go to case 2. However if I remove break from first case it will jump to case 2 and apply vm.vehicle.detail = true; even though the case condition isn't met.

So if I remove break in the first case, my object will look like this anyway

```
{ main: true, detail: true }
```

If I don't it will look like this

```
{ main: true, detail: false }
```

How do I meet both conditions on single run of the switch?

Comment: Then don't do a `switch`, but two `if` instead…!?

Comment: @deceze but there are more states within the switch. I've only pasted an example. switch statement is really clear to read in my case and having lots of ifs is just terrible.

Comment: I think the principle of switch is to have only 1 case that fits. if you need more cases check on the if side.

Comment: I know a lot of you are trying to help but you're missing my point. Maybe I wasn't too clear in my description. I'm not necessarily trying to find other ways to do it. I only want to know whether it's possible to match two cases in a switch.

Comment: No, it's not. That's not how a `switch` works.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just take the comparisons as values for the object?

```
var vehicle = {
        main: states.data.currentState.indexOf('main.vehicle') !== -1,
        detail: states.data.currentState === main.vehicle.detail
    };
```

ES6

```
var vehicle = {
        main: states.data.currentState.includes('main.vehicle'),
        detail: states.data.currentState === main.vehicle.detail
    };
```